# Finding arduino bootloader version?

Tags: bootloader

I have problem with WDT reset. After reset the device goes on for a boot loop. from the following link https://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=181
It has been mentioned that there is problem with Bootloader because some of them does not support wdt properly.How can i find which version of bootloader is running in my arduino mega 2560 . Which version of bootloader support wdt properly? where these bootloaders can be found?

Answer (score 1):

In all practicality; put a known boot loader on it. Because if it is a problem version you will need to replace it anyways.

The Mega uses STK500 protocol. Which only shows a command to read its type (or signature) and not its version of firmware.

It is a good exercise, but not really worth the time to go deeper into it, as programmers are cheap and or you can use another Arduino as the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The watchdog timer will reset the Arduino in case of a timeout. The way to prevent this from happening is to catch the WDT interrupt.

```
ISR(WDT_vect)
{
  // do nothing
}
```

This has nothing to do with the bootloader. The fix suggested in the link above only makes the bootloader detect a reset triggered by a WDT event, and have it not add any delay. This delay is normally needed to see if the usb-host is trying to upload a new program.